# Sort pandas df into individual columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to `sort` a `pandas df` into individual `columns` based on when values in `columns` change. For the `df` below I can sort the df into separate `columns` when a values changes in `Col B`. But I'm trying to add `Col C`so it's when values change in both `Col B` and `Col C`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A' : [10,20,30,40,40,30,20,10,5,10,15,20,20,15,10,5],
        'B' : ['X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y'],
        'C' : ['W','W','Z','Z','Z','Z','W','W','W','W','Z','Z','Z','Z','W','W'],                                         
        })

d = df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift()).cumsum()
df['C'] =  d.groupby(df['B']).transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).add(1).astype(str)
df['D'] = df.groupby(['B','C']).cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['D','C','B'])['A'].unstack([2,1])
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
```

Output:

```
   X1  Y1  X2  Y2
D                
0  10  40   5  20
1  20  30  10  15
2  30  20  15  10
3  40  10  20   5
```

As you can see, this creates a new `column` every time there's a new value in `Col B`. But I'm trying to incorporate `Col C` as well. So it should be every time there's a change in both `Col B` and `Col C`.

Intended output:

```
   XW1  XZ1  YZ1  YW1  XW2  XZ2  YZ2  YW2
0   10   30   40   20    5   15   20   10
1   20   40   30   10   10   20   15    5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just base on your out put create the help columns one by one.

```
df['key']=df.B+df.C# create the key
df['key2']=(df.key!=df.key.shift()).ne(0).cumsum() # make the continue key into one group
df.key2=df.groupby('key').key2.apply(lambda x : x.astype('category').cat.codes+1)# change the group number to 1 or 2 
df['key3']=df.groupby(['key','key2']).cumcount() # create the index for pivot
df['key']=df.key+df.key2.astype(str) # create the columns for pivot

df.pivot('key3','key','A')#yield  
Out[126]: 
key   XW1  XW2  XZ1  XZ2  YW1  YW2  YZ1  YZ2
key3                                        
0      10    5   30   15   20   10   40   20
1      20   10   40   20   10    5   30   15
```